# AWS API Gateway custom authorizer unexpected timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have regularly (each ~7 hours) unexpected waiting time before receiving response from Custom Authorizer.

My systems:

- API Gateway endpoints with custom authorizer
- A lambda who validate the token (lambda-auth)
- A lambda who is called every 5 mins by a cloudwatch event (lambda-test)

The lambda-test calls the api gateway endpoints:

```
response1 = requests.get(api1, auth=AUTH, timeout=4)
response2 = requests.get(api2, auth=AUTH, timeout=4)
```

Every ~7 hours, both requests timeout, as shown in the cloudwatch logs :

```
07:22:11 START RequestId: beabb449-a41d-11e7-8469-93a8731ae2d8 Version: $LATEST
07:22:16 HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<host>', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=4)
07:22:20 HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<host>', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=4)
07:22:20 END RequestId: beabb449-a41d-11e7-8469-93a8731ae2d8
07:22:20 REPORT RequestId: beabb449-a41d-11e7-8469-93a8731ae2d8 Duration: 8407.03 ms Billed Duration: 8500 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 36 MB
```

[Cloudwatch metrics of lambda-test duration: a peak every ~7h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZiW4.png) (the peak high changed because I changed the timeout from 2s to 4s a few days ago)

For the requests who happened at 07:22:11:

```
07:22:11 start lambda-test
07:22:11 try to connect to api1
07:22:12 start authorizer for api1's call
07:22:16 lambda-test: api1 timeout
07:22:16 try to connect to api2
07:22:16 start authorizer for api2's call
07:22:19 start lambda-auth for api1's call
07:22:19 end lambda-auth for api1's call
07:22:19 authorizer sucessfull for api1's call
07:22:19 start lambda-auth for api2's call
07:22:20 end lambda-auth for api2's call
07:22:20 authorizer sucessfull for api2's call
07:22:20 lambda-test: api2 timeout
07:22:20 end lambda-test
```

If someone have hints about from where this authorizer latency could come, it would be great !

Thank you for your time,

here are all the corresponding logs for each part of the system:

lambda-test:

```
07:22:11 START RequestId: beabb449-a41d-11e7-8469-93a8731ae2d8 Version: $LATEST
07:22:16 HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<host>', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=4)
07:22:20 HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<host>', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=4)
07:22:20 END RequestId: beabb449-a41d-11e7-8469-93a8731ae2d8
07:22:20 REPORT RequestId: beabb449-a41d-11e7-8469-93a8731ae2d8 Duration: 8407.03 ms Billed Duration: 8500 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 36 MB
```

api gateway for api1:

```
07:22:12 Starting authorizer: 2szewn for request: bee365d6-a41d-11e7-9709-8d6614596919
07:22:12 Incoming identity: ********************************************************YzNw==
07:22:19 Using valid authorizer policy for principal: ****E_1
07:22:19 Successfully completed authorizer execution
07:22:19 Verifying Usage Plan for request: bee365d6-a41d-11e7-9709-8d6614596919. API Key: API Stage: 41clweydfc/dev
07:22:19 API Key authorized because method 'GET /api1' does not require API Key. Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits
07:22:19 Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage 41clweydfc/dev
07:22:19 Starting execution for request: bee365d6-a41d-11e7-9709-8d6614596919
07:22:19 HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /api1
07:22:20 Successfully completed execution
07:22:20 (bee365d6-a41d-11e7-9709-8d6614596919) Method completed with status: 200
```

api gateway for api2:

```
07:22:16 Starting authorizer: 2szewn for request: c15724e7-a41d-11e7-811a-6dd1376e9475
07:22:16 Incoming identity: ********************************************************YzNw==
07:22:20 Using valid authorizer policy for principal: ****E_1
07:22:20 Successfully completed authorizer execution
07:22:20 Verifying Usage Plan for request: c15724e7-a41d-11e7-811a-6dd1376e9475. API Key: API Stage: 41clweydfc/dev
07:22:20 API Key authorized because method 'GET /api2' does not require API Key. Request will not contribute to throttle or quota limits
07:22:20 Usage Plan check succeeded for API Key and API Stage 41clweydfc/dev
07:22:20 Starting execution for request: c15724e7-a41d-11e7-811a-6dd1376e9475
07:22:20 HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /api2
07:22:20 Successfully completed execution
07:22:20 Method completed with status: 200
```

lambda-auth for ap1's call:

```
07:22:19 START RequestId: beeadfbb-a41d-11e7-82fd-cf842bd93e85 Version: $LATEST
07:22:19 END RequestId: beeadfbb-a41d-11e7-82fd-cf842bd93e85
07:22:19 REPORT RequestId: beeadfbb-a41d-11e7-82fd-cf842bd93e85 Duration: 195.75 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 25 MB
```

lambda-auth for api2's call:

```
07:22:19 START RequestId: c15db514-a41d-11e7-88e3-1f6800c6e34e Version: $LATEST
07:22:20 END RequestId: c15db514-a41d-11e7-88e3-1f6800c6e34e
07:22:20 REPORT RequestId: c15db514-a41d-11e7-88e3-1f6800c6e34e Duration: 78.51 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 25 MB
```

Comment: Is your Lambda function running in a VPC?  This *might* suggest that you may have it on one subnet (mis-)configured differently than the others.

Comment: The lambda-auth, who is called by the custom authorizer, is running in a VPC.

The 2 subnets are the same: subnet1 is 10.10.3.0\24, in eu-central-1a, and subnet2 is 10.10.4.0\24, in eu-central-1b.

It is in a VPC because it need to access a RDS database (mysql).

The RDS database is only in eu-central-1a, with subnet1 and subnet2, and with MULTI-AZ = no.

So, it could be related with that ? I don't understand why it is so regular...

Comment: (the security groups (egress and ingress) are well configured, so the lambda can join the RDS in both AZ)

Comment: You could temporarily remove one of the two subnets from the Lambda function.  If the issue is related to a problem with one subnet, the problem will go away or the function will fail completely.  Or... if you are persisting a MySQL connection between function invocations, it seems likely that you may be running into a situation where a container is left with a connection it believes to be usable but which the server has abandoned or the network has severed.  The default `idle_timeout` in MySQL is 8 hours.  Coincidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to the kill of the VPC by aws-lambda and the time to make it up again. ([cf. amazon aws forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=756733#756734))

Increasing the timeouts solved the problem.